# What Sci-Fi book about robot domination is this?

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots

Looking for help to find a book I read maybe 30 years ago.
The main thread was about robots eventually taking control over man. There is a central leader robot who comes to power. The key fact I recall is that the robots bore an emblem of a stylised cog that they had adopted as their symbol.

There are also streamlined flying robots with tendril arms.

I think the same book contained a human character who spent a part of the story in suspended animation in a spaceship in orbit (around the sun or moon?), eventually being rescued and finding how the robots had taken control in the meantime.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253051/1960s-novel-opens-with-astronaut-waking-from-suspended-animation-to-witness-dest (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

This answer is very late, but this book is unquestionably *[After World's End](https://archive.org/details/Marvel_v01n03_1939-02/page/n7/mode/2up)* (1939), by Jack Williamson.  It is a short novel, and it was most frequently found bound in a single volume along with another short novel Williamson wrote, *The Legion of Time*

The protagonist, Barry Horn, is a man from (roughly) present-day Earth, who is placed in suspended animation in space, where he survives the destruction of the Earth.  The antagonist is Malgarth, the first intelligent robot, who exerts hegemony over the interstellar civilization through control over technology, which is produced only his company, the Robot Corporation, staffed entirely by robots Malgarth created, all stamped with his toothed gear logo.  Near the end, when the heroes storm Malgarth's fortress, they find the sleek, beautiful flying robots waiting for them at the "mirror of darkness" at the bottom of a shaft.

(The question actually does not mention the one thing I found really memorable about the book, which was a billion-year-old silicon-based starfish-like alien.)

Comment: The original magazine version is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Marvel_v01n03_1939-02).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps: [The Humanoid Touch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030560527) (1980) by Jack Williamson

> The humanoids, an ultra-mechanical race created by man, have pursued
>   the last remnants of mankind to a remote galactic outpost. One man, a
>   member of the planet's ruling class, comes across a secret force that
>   could be the only hope of defeating the machines.